# How to get cyrillic symbol by it's code

Tags: python, encoding, cyrillic

I can get code of cyrillic symbol. For example

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s = u'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
print ord(s[0])

1072
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

But I can't get cyrillic symbol by it's code. Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unichr(1072)
>> u'\u0430'

print unichr(1072)
>> а
```

Comment: oh my God, so simple. I used chr(1072). Of course it doesn't work. But there is unichr(1072)!!! I didn't know. Thenks a lot

Comment: Use Python3, it's time to upgrade.